# daily update mysql in wordpress server using php code

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, api

Here is my plan. I will appreciate it if you put a comment on my plan.

I am planning to display a html table based on db which is updated once in a day in my wordpress page.
To do that, I am considering to embed php code in a php file in wordpress server to update mysql once in a day.

The php code I want to include is about calling data from my local api server and put it into mysql db in wordpress server once in a day.

Frankly, I planned to put javascript to create html table by reading api data. But traffic on api server may be worrisome. So I changed my initial plan. On the wordpress hosting server, with php code that i embed, I trying to call api data and tranfer it into mysql in wordpress server.

Is it a good idea or plz recommend any alternative option available~!!

Comment: It's a plan. It'll probably work. Will it be better than just querying the API from JavaScript? Maybe. We have no idea what traffic you'll be generating, or how important the latency will be in your site. Beware premature optimisation. Don't fix problems you don't have.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Your question is written in a way that invites people to offer individual opinions instead of definitive answers _ This is not allowed here _ Please visit SO Help Center & specifically the section on what type of questions are acceptable >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask